# ruby operator overloading question

Tags: ruby, operators, operator-overloading, overloading

i've been messing around with ruby and opengl for entertainment purposes, and i decided to write some 3d vector/plane/etc classes to pretty up some of the math.

simplified example:

```
class Vec3
    attr_accessor :x,:y,:z

    def *(a)
        if a.is_a?(Numeric) #multiply by scalar
            return Vec3.new(@x*a, @y*a, @z*a)
        elsif a.is_a?(Vec3) #dot product
            return @x*a.x + @y*a.y + @z*a.z
        end
    end
end

v1 = Vec3.new(1,1,1)
v2 = v1*5 #produces [5,5,5]
```

which all fine and dandy, but i also want to be able to write

```
v2 = 5*v1
```

which requires adding functionality to Fixnum or Float or whatever, but i couldn't find a way to overload or extend fixnum's multiplication without replacing it entirely. is this possible in ruby? any tips?

(obviously i can just write all my multiplications in the correct order if i need to)

Comment: Just for the record, change `@x*s, @y*s, @z*s` to `@x*a, @y*a, @z*a`, otherwise your code is broken.

Comment: thanks, copied code from 2 places at once >< should be fixed now

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using coerce is a MUCH better approach than monkey-patching a core class:

```
class Vec3
    attr_accessor :x,:y,:z

    def *(a)
        if a.is_a?(Numeric) #multiply by scalar
            return Vec3.new(@x*a, @y*a, @z*a)
        elsif a.is_a?(Vec3) #dot product
            return @x*a.x + @y*a.y + @z*a.z
        end
    end

    def coerce(other)
        return self, other
    end
end
```

if you define v as `v = Vec3.new` then the following will work: `v * 5` and `5 * v`
The first element returned by coerce (self) becomes the new receiver for the operation, and the second element (other) becomes the parameter, so `5 * v` is exactly equivalent to `v * 5`

Comment: +1 for coerce. On behalf of the person who has to debug your code, please don't monkeypatch core classes unless super-duper-absolutely necessary.

Comment: this worked great for what i needed. if i run into a similar example that can't be commutative then i suppose i'll monkey patch as needed ;)

Comment: Coerce should always return `self` as the second argument! Otherwise you mess up the commutativity of the arguments. Instead, `coerce` should cast the argument to a type that can be multiplied (for example by: `Vec3.new(other, other, other)`). Obviously this is not without it's own problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you want, though [banister's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854203/ruby-operator-overloading-question/1854636#1854636) to use `coerce` instead of monkey-patching `Numeric` is a preferred method. Use this method only if necessary (for example if you only want *some* binary operands to be transitive).

```
Fixnum.class_eval do
  original_times = instance_method(:*)
  define_method(:*) do |other|
    if other.kind_of?(Vec3)
      return other * self
    else
      return original_times.bind(self).call(other)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: mmm sexy :) btw, i needed to change the first line to "Fixnum.class_eval do" or (the equivalent?) "class Fixnum"

Comment: is it not possible just to define it directly on Fixnum class without the class_eval, and to do a regular def rather than a define_method ?

Comment: ok, this code is crazy :) not only do you not need a class_eval (an ordinary class body will do fine) you are doing ridiculous things with unbound method objects that are completely unnecessary. Why not just use alias_method instead? ;)

Not to mention that monkey-patching a core class is a huge no-no too :)

Comment: `alias_method` unnecessarily pollutes the namespace. This idiom is neither "ridiculous" (it is a well-known idiom, the inner workings of which as well as the necessity have been well-documented in many a blog post) nor is it "completely unnecessary" (it is, in fact, the *only* idiom known to work, AFAIK).

Comment: I am sure it's a good idiom to use in _some_ circumstances, but not in this case. And your argument regarding alias_method 'polluting' the namespace' is weak at best in _this_ context where an even greater evil (monkey-patching a core class) is being committed.

If you have a link to a blog explaining the usefulness of the binding-unbound-method idiom is useful in THIS context (where afaik most people just use alias method chaining) then post it here :)

Comment: I'm not really *for* monkey-patching core classes, but this sort of commutivity problem is well-established in object-oriented programming. And Jörg Mittag is exactly right about why I suggested the unbound method instead of `alias_method` -- there wouldn't be any reason to call `original_times`, so I prevented people from doing so. It would just complicate the API.

Comment: banister's suggestion for `coerce` is a much better solution for the commutivity problem, though. +1 for it.

Comment: Oh, and banister: an "ordinary class body" will work fine for Numeric, which is surely defined at this point, but is dangerous in other cases, as it might prevent an `autoload` statement from firing.