# Ruby operator overloading

Tags: ruby

I have a specific class `C` and I would like to overload some math operators.

I already overloaded `+`, `i`, `*`, and `/` so that I can do things like

```
a = C.new
b = C.new
a + b
a + 2
a + 2.0
```

To treat the last three cases, I am systematically testing for the type of the operand: is it `C`, `Fixnum` or `Float`, other possibilities are rejected. My first question is: is it the right way to do that?

Next I also want to be able to do

```
2.0 + A
```

How should I do it? Should I provide a conversion of some sort? Can these two problems be solved by the same method?

Comment: You can't do operator overloading in Ruby, only redefine the methods that the operators call (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `<`, `>`, ...), if the operator calls a method. But there is no way to overload `=` in ruby.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Does Ruby Only Permit Certain Operator Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92862/why-does-ruby-only-permit-certain-operator-overloading)

Comment: @the Tin Man : I don't how this could possibly be a duplicate of that question ...

Comment: @Tass: OK, so this is not overloading of the operators but of the methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer to "[ruby operator overloading question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854203/ruby-operator-overloading-question?rq=1)" addresses both your points by using `is_a?` and `coerce`.

With regards to your first point. The normal approach in Ruby is to use `respond_to?` where possible, rather than checking for type. If for some reason you specifically need to check for type, then using `is_a?` is the correct way.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about coerce.